# Java enum-alternative mapping

Tags: java, orm, enums, mapping, constants

Trying to create my own shiny ORM system (not that important information), I'm currently struggling with java inheritance limits. Here is the concept:

```
public class UserDescriptor implements TableDescriptor {
    public static final UserDescriptor INSTANCE = new UserDescriptor();

    private UserDescriptor() {
    }

    public String getTableName() {
        return "user";
    }

    // ======= Columns definition
    public static final AbstractColumn<Integer> ID =
        new IntegerColumn("id", AbstractColumn.Attribute.NOT_NULL);

    public static final AbstractColumn<String> ALIAS =
        new StringColumn("alias");

    // ... and some more...
}
```

Hope it's clear enough. These are then used with static import like:

```
map = JDBCHelper.selectFirst(UserDescriptor.INSTANCE, Arrays.asList(ID, ALIAS));
```

where the list (2. param) is what I need to fetch from table defined by UserDescriptor. `map` variable holds custom map, which internally has signature similar to `<AbstractColumn<T>, T>` and method

```
public T getValue(AbstractColumn<T> col);
```

so I'm getting the value then type-safe

```
    Integer id = map.getValue(ID);
    String alias = map.getValue(ALIAS);
```

---

This concept is currently working, but:

TableDescriptor concept is a bit verbose. I have many tables and need many times to write twice the type and this long start of each column definition

```
public static final AbstractColumn<Integer>
```

This line is result of well-know java limitation - not possible to extend enum class. Otherwise the `TableDescriptor` would be abstract class with field `AbstractColumn<T>` defined by explicit constructor and every successor would be enum with columns defined within instances.
This would come with following advantages:

1. Possibility to make whole thing (conditions, returning columns definition, .....) more type-safe, eg. only enum of specific type can be listed in List parameter for select from single table,
2. better readability and basis for new developers,
3. `getAllColumns` functionality can be done without reflection.

This is unfortunately not possible, so you're now my last hope. I know enum inheritance stuff is on SO many times, but I already have already working solution and maybe it's possible to improve it some other way in this specific case..

What may be some kind of hint - these descriptors must now be int the API part of project to selects to be possible. I was struggling with the way I'd put it to impl. and in API I'll let only some enum listing only overview of the columns:

```
public enum UserTableColumns {
    ID,
    ALIAS
}
```

and map it somehow to UserDescriptor - then I'd be able to use in most cases only this enum, but I didn't figure out yet how this should work..

Current signature of `selectFisrt` method is following:

```
CustomResultMap selectFirst(TableDescriptor td, List<AbstractColumn<?>> cols);
```

and one possible modification would be to change `List<AbstractColumn<?>>` to some list of enum values, which will be mapped to `TableDescriptor` so I can check that the values are from single table.

Edit: clarification

Comment: I'm not quite sure I get what you want to do so let me summarize: you have an enum that defines the available columns like `UserTableColumns` and you want those enums to be part of the API while the table descriptors like `UserDescriptor` are part of the impl? And finally you want `JDBCHelper.selectFirst(TableDescriptor,List<Enum>)` to only allow enums that match the descriptor? Could you provide a (pseudo code) example of how you'd like to use it/what is should look like ideally?

Comment: Yes, you're right somehow.. Currently I have `UserDescriptor` in API and not yet use `UserTableColumns`. Signature of `selectFirst` method is `selectFirst(TableDescriptor, List<AbstractColumn<?>>`

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't a map like `Map<UserTableColumns, AbstractColumn<?>>` in `UserDescriptor` provide what you need? It might actually be like `TableDescriptor<E extends Enum<E>> { Map<E, AbstractColumn<?>> m; }` and `UserDescriptor extends TableDescriptor<UserTableColumns>`.

Comment: Then, you'll loose the column type information during fetching the column values from the result map.. From what I now see - you'll loose it anyway, when you create the enum `UserTableColumns` without type information..

Comment: Ah I see, so `getValue(ID)` would actually look like `T getValue( AbstractColumn<T>)`, right?

Comment: Exactly like you wrote.. Sorry not to clarify it before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125180/discussion-between-tcigler-and-thomas).

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to summarize what I understood from your question and the comments:

Your API should contain an enum like `UserTableColumn` as well as a method that currently looks like `T get(AbstractColumn<T>)` but should return the correct type based on the generic type of the column. Since `AbstractColumn` basically is meant to be an implementation detail you'd like to replace that with the enum, e.g. to get something like this (which won't compile): `T get(UserTableColumn<T>)`.

(Please correct me if I made a mistake somewhere.)

The problem with that is that generics are a compile time tool, i.e. the compiler needs to know about the type that is being used. However, enum values can't have generic types and any parameter (e.g. `ID(Integer.class)`) would not be available at compile time since it's basically an instance (i.e. runtime) value.

Thus you'll need something like `AbstractColumn<T>` although that might be another class that only contains the generic type (and implements some interface). That probably requires some manual definition or the use of a preprocessor (have a look at how Hibernate does it for its criteria api).

Comment: The main reason I started this question is that you should not be able to write `selectFirst(UserDescriptor.INSTANCE, Arrays.asList(UserDescriptor.ID, ItemDescriptor.NAME))`. In case of another class, this will only help me with separating impl. from API, not the type safety..